# Brand new install but class not found

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have PHP 8.18 installed. I would like to use PHPspreadsheet, so I installed it via composer as per instructions on the Github page. It's a default install so nothing was changed before or after the install.

I entered the following code as per instructions on the readthedocs page:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '') . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
```

When I run the file I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet" not found
```

How are you supposed to do it then, if the default way to install and use it, is not working? VS Code even suggested the file where the class is located, so why does it not find the class? Any other spreadsheet library I can use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123687/class-phpoffice-phpspreadsheet-spreadsheet-not-found)

Comment: Not really because I did not do anything. I did not move any files. I just did a basic install per the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I have the import for the library (vendor/autoload.php) in the index file of my app, but the code I want to run is in another file that is not called from within index or within another file that is called from within index so the file I am trying to test with doesn't know about the import. Apologies for wasting anybody's time but still learning